# Mysql only %LIKE% works

Tags: mysql, sql-like, varchar

I have a column with different ASIN in it.
The column is varchar(255) utf8_general_ci.
I want to search for a value for example: B074SJBC53

```
SELECT * FROM  `products_stock` WHERE  `asin` LIKE  'B074SJBC53'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM  `products_stock` WHERE  `asin` =  'B074SJBC53'
```

don't work!

```
SELECT * FROM  `products_stock` WHERE  `asin` LIKE  '%B074SJBC53%'
```

works but I think it's not secure enough.

How comes that if I copy & paste the value in phpMyAdmin I got no results even if it's in the database? B074SJBC53 is the exact value - there are no spaces before or after or hidden chars.

**Solution: I've updated the whole column with**

```
preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $all['asin']);
```

**it seems that there were hidden control characters. It works now.**

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM  products_stock WHERE  trim(asin) =  'B074SJBC53'` work? Also this is just a MySQL question, PHP shouldn't be tagged. PHP runs `phpmyadmin` but your question has nothing to do with PHP itself.

Comment: There must be *something* before or after ... could you try `SELECT SHA1(\`asin\`) ...` and compare that to an sha1 value created elsewhere from that string?

Comment: what if you type it rather than copy paste?

Comment: what if you paste it into notepad, then copy it from notepad and then paste it in to phpmyadmin?

Comment: i've tried all of them but didn't work till now

Comment: I have deleted the row and entered all manually and then still got no search results on that column without LIKE %value%

Comment: if you are using phpMyadmin, try in phpMyadmin search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Nawin i've used the phpMyAdmin search and it also gave me back no results. Could the table be broken or something like that?

Comment: @Martin i've tried all the above and even combined them - but I still get no results from the query.

Comment: @Andrew tried this with Notepad and Notepad++ and it doesn't gave me any results.

Comment: I found that there are hidden symbols or something like that but trim() doesn't solve this problem. Is there another way to filter hidden symbols or characters?
I can't select the hidden symbols - and I can't understand why. I have to delete the complete field, press a few times DEL and Backspace and than enter the Value manually. CTRL + A and Backspace didn't work.

Comment: If you check with phpMyadmin you can get correct query, Otherwise there is some problem in you column value.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [INSTR()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php):

```
SELECT *
FROM  `products_stock`
WHERE INSTR(`asin`, 'B074SJBC53') > 0
```

Comment: How is that better than `LIKE  '%B074SJBC53%'` - which OP don't like :-)

Comment: The problem with this is, that it could end with more than one result. So i've to compare the exact value not only an occurance in a string.